# System crashes when multiple monitors is turned on via VGA

Tags: vga, multiple-monitors

I am trying to get my multiple screens to work (double screen) on a second monitor I have connected through a VGA cable, but the system crashes whenever I turn the duplicate mode on by pressing "screen switching". Basically, I cannot have both monitor lighted on because the system crashes. I must say that HDMI works fine but VGA is giving me problems. Also I tried to use the `xradr` command, all outputs work fine as they are connected but when I run `xrandr --output LVDS --primary --auto --output VGA-0 --right-of LVDS --auto` only one screen works whereas the other doesn't.

Below there *should* be the log of the error

```
Sep  2 17:37:46 Alessio-PC systemd[1832]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Sep  2 17:37:46 Alessio-PC dbus-daemon[1858]: Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Sep  2 17:37:46 Alessio-PC systemd[1832]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Sep  2 17:37:47 Alessio-PC unity-control-c[2650]: State 0 for FooScrollArea 0x559aa638d8c0 doesn't match state 192 set via gtk_style_context_set_state ()
Sep  2 17:37:47 Alessio-PC unity-control-c[2650]: State 0 for FooScrollArea 0x559aa638d8c0 doesn't match state 192 set via gtk_style_context_set_state ()
Sep  2 17:37:47 Alessio-PC unity-control-c[2650]: State 4 for FooScrollArea 0x559aa638d8c0 doesn't match state 192 set via gtk_style_context_set_state ()
Sep  2 17:38:33 Alessio-PC unity-control-c[2650]: State 0 for FooScrollArea 0x559aa638d8c0 doesn't match state 128 set via gtk_style_context_set_state ()
Sep  2 17:38:33 Alessio-PC unity-control-c[2650]: State 0 for FooScrollArea 0x559aa638d8c0 doesn't match state 128 set via gtk_style_context_set_state ()
Sep  2 17:38:33 Alessio-PC unity-control-c[2650]: State 4 for FooScrollArea 0x559aa638d8c0 doesn't match state 128 set via gtk_style_context_set_state ()
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC dbus[850]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC unity-control-c[2650]: State 0 for FooScrollArea 0x559aa638d8c0 doesn't match state 192 set via gtk_style_context_set_state ()
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC unity-control-c[2650]: State 0 for FooScrollArea 0x559aa638d8c0 doesn't match state 192 set via gtk_style_context_set_state ()
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC unity-control-c[2650]: State 4 for FooScrollArea 0x559aa638d8c0 doesn't match state 192 set via gtk_style_context_set_state ()
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: message repeated 4 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied]
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC dbus[850]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Sep  2 17:38:34 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:38:51 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: message repeated 134 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied]
Sep  2 17:38:52 Alessio-PC dbus-daemon[1858]: Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit'
Sep  2 17:38:52 Alessio-PC dbus-daemon[1858]: Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'
Sep  2 17:38:53 Alessio-PC gedit[2773]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:39:13 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/alessio/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file “/home/alessio/.local/share/recently-used.xbel”: Permission denied.
Sep  2 17:39:13 Alessio-PC zeitgeist-datah[2617]: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/alessio/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file “/home/alessio/.local/share/recently-used.xbel”: Permission denied.
Sep  2 17:39:29 Alessio-PC zeitgeist-datah[2617]: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/alessio/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file “/home/alessio/.local/share/recently-used.xbel”: Permission denied.
Sep  2 17:39:29 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/alessio/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file “/home/alessio/.local/share/recently-used.xbel”: Permission denied.
Sep  2 17:39:46 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:39:46 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:39:46 Alessio-PC zeitgeist-daemon[2626]: #033[31m[15:39:46.412210 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!
Sep  2 17:40:54 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:41:02 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: message repeated 117 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied]
Sep  2 17:41:03 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
Sep  2 17:41:07 Alessio-PC zeitgeist-fts[2634]: Unable to get info on application://nautilus-autostart.desktop
Sep  2 17:41:07 Alessio-PC gedit[2840]: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/alessio/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file “/home/alessio/.local/share/recently-used.xbel”: Permission denied.
Sep  2 17:41:08 Alessio-PC gedit[2840]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:41:08 Alessio-PC hud-service[2584]: #033[31mvoid DBusMenuImporter::slotGetLayoutFinished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)#033[0m: "No such interface 'com.canonical.dbusmenu' on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/window/67108996"
Sep  2 17:41:59 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:41:59 Alessio-PC nautilus[2371]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:41:59 Alessio-PC gedit[2840]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:41:59 Alessio-PC gedit[2840]: message repeated 2 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied]
Sep  2 17:41:59 Alessio-PC gedit[2840]: Set document metadata failed: Error setting file metadata: can't open metadata tree
Sep  2 17:41:59 Alessio-PC gedit[2840]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:41:59 Alessio-PC gedit[2840]: can't init metadata tree /home/alessio/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Sep  2 17:41:59 Alessio-PC gedit[2840]: Set document metadata failed: Error setting file metadata: can't open metadata tree
```

Comment: Have a look at /var/log/ and the log that gets info added to when you do a `ls -ltr` (once before and once after a crash) and post the message about the crash into the question, please.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how to do it.